# What Format is Sound Stored in? OpenAL / SFML

Tags: c++, sfml, openal

I know how to make a `sf::SoundBuffer` and stuff like that, but how do I, for example, create a short pitch noise programmatically that SFML would be able to read. Or how would I go over creating a noise that gradually increases in volume or gets higher/lower pitched?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sf::SoundBuffer` with `loadFromSamples` (see the [documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1SoundBuffer.php#a63da986e144b578135edd48e51c565e8)).

The representation of a sound in memory is basically a large array of integers that gives the amplitude of the signal at a given time. You can provide your own array to a `sf::SoundBuffer` with the correct parameters, and that would give you your programmatically generated sound.

For manipulation of sound, volume etc I can't help you though, you'll have to search for the maths behind signal processing and such.

Comment: So if I create a stereo sample, would that mean that I should pass samples and set it to half the size of the array?

Comment: And which data would represent the left speaker, and which data the right?

Comment: The `channelCount` parameter tells wether it's a mono, stereo sound or whatever. I bet that if it's provided with stereo, SFML will assume that 2 contiguous samples represent the left/right output. But you'd better ask on the forums (http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/) to be sure.